# What options does JModelAdmin method loadForm expect in the $options parameter?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

What options does the [JModelForm::loadForm](https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JModelForm::loadForm) method expect in its' $options array parameter.

So far I have found that it expects
'control' => $var
and
'load_data' => $var
When I came accross this SO question: [JForm::getInstance could not load file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314306/jformgetinstance-could-not-load-file)

Are there any more parameters that it will expect, I cannot find them listed anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code, it looks like the options are being passed to getInstance() in JModelLegacy, and then on to the constructor of the same class. The docs say here the constructor options can be the following:

> @param   array  $config  An array of configuration options (name, state, dbo, table_path, ignore_request).

but there seems to also be a event_clean_cache - option, to set event handling for onContentCleanCache.

Comment: Interesting I will unset the 'control' k,v pair to see if it is used at all, where did you find the source? Just in your Joomla installation I guess?

Comment: Yes, I just searched my installation...